# どうしてこの「が」は動詞に付いていますか。

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs, particle-が

「手さぐり」という章を読んでいる最中、ややこしい助詞の用法にあいました。

> （前略）
>
> 目の見えない人は手さぐりで歩む。一歩一歩が慎重である。謙虚である。そして一足歩むために全神経を集中する。これほど真剣な歩み方は、目の見える人にはちょっとあるまい。
>
> 人生で思わぬケガをしたくなければ、そして世の中でつまずきたくなければ、この歩み方を**見習うが**いい。
>
> （後略）

「が」という助詞は、一般的に**名詞**につくと思いますが、どうしてこの「が」は**動詞**についているでしょうか。

Comment: これですね：　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/9831

Comment: ありがとうございます！ということでみなさん、質問をcloseするようにしたほうがいいと思えばそうしてください。