# understanding であると同時に construction

Tags: grammar, translation, copula

> やけに高く響くその靴音は、スバルにとって焦燥感の原因**であると同時に**、心の拠り所でもあった。

So I basically translate it as **"For Subaru, those footsteps that echoed absurdly loud were, at the same time, the source of his impatience and also the one thing he could rely on."**

What confuses me here is **「であると同時に」**. It is the same as **「だと同時に」**, right? Either way, I don't understand this construction/grammar.

I was thinking that maybe it would be ok to rephrase it like this:

> やけに高く響くその靴音は、スバルにとって**同時に**焦燥感の原因**と**、心の拠り所でもあった。

Also, despite the grammar points, is my translation close enough? Those are the first lines of a book I'm reading btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デジタル大辞泉 says this type of と同時に is a special case where the whole combination of と同時に works like a conjunctive particle:

> #### [同時に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/155915/meaning/m0u/)
>
> ３ （「…と同時に」の形で**接続助詞的に**用いて）
>   ㋐…すると同じ時に。…するとすぐに。「夜が明けると同時に出発した」
>   ㋑…とともに。…だけでなく、加えて。「他人に厳しいと同時に自分にも厳しい」

I may be wrong, but I feel this is a remnant of classic grammar, and there is a [hidden nominalization](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010) in this construction. ～であると同時に is interchangeable with ～である**の**と同時に, where の is a nominalizer and と is [a comparison target marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57077/5010). So Aである(の)と同時にB basically means "while (being) A, (also) B", "in addition to being A, (also) B", "A, but at the same time, B" or "not only A but also B".

However, ～だと同時に is ungrammatical. If I understand this correctly, this is because the verb/adjective before と must be in the attributive form (連体形). だ is the predicative form (終止形) of the copula.

同時にAでありBで(も)ある is semantically similar, but it is simply "both A and B at the same time", where the two items are treated equally. Aであると同時にB sounds a little more emphatic or rhetorical to me.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea behind the grammar Aと同時にB is that A happens at the same time as B or that something or someone is in both state A and state B.

According to a [Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar](https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/entries/360.html), the pattern is as such:

> Noun + と同時に
>
> Verb plain + と同時に
>
> Na-adjective/Noun + であると同時に +  Na-adjective/Noun + でもある

Here it's saying that for Subaru, the 靴音 was both 焦燥感の原因 as well as 心の拠り所.

EDIT: Okay, after some more prodding from Chocolate and some thinking/consulting with others, I think I figured out the difference between noun+であると同時に and noun+と同時に.

noun+であると同時に means that the noun is describing the state of the subject/topic. So in this case, 焦燥感の原因 is describing something about of その靴音.

noun + と同時に doesn't have this relationship to the subject/topic.

Comment: What's the difference between Noun + と同時に and Noun + であると同時に? Just the level of politeness?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yes, it's seen as more formal so it's used more often in formal speeches and in writing.

Comment: ^「Nounと同時に」and「Nounであると同時に」have different meanings, ね? 「卒業と同時に就職した」「社長であると同時に大株主でもある」「安全であると同時に効率がいい」「医者であると同時に小説家でもあった」can't be rephrased as 「卒業であると同時に就職..」「社長と同時に大株主..」「安全と同時に効率が..」「医者と同時に小説家..」

Comment: `for nouns that are acting as suru-verbs you must use Noun + と同時に. Meanwhile, nouns that are not acting as/cannot act as suru-verbs should use であると同時に` -- いえ、そういうことではなくて・・　In the same page you can also find examples: 「 **銃声と**同時に警官の一人が倒れた」「私は**ルースと**同時に日本語の勉強を始めた」, right? Compare: 「社長**だ** 。+ 大株主だ。→ 社長**である**と同時に大株主でもある」「安全**だ** 。+ 効率がいい。→ 安全**である**と同時に効率がいい」「医者**だった** 。+ 小説家だった。→ 医者**である**と同時に小説家でもあった」 VS 「卒業と同じときに就職した→ 卒業と同時に就職した」「ルースと同じときに始めた → ルースと同時に始めた」 (Examples taken from [と同時に--DoJG](https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/entries/360.html))

Comment: @Chocolate I really appreciate you pointing out my errors. Hopefully I have the correct understanding now.