# What are the differences between うちに、間に、同時に, ながら & ついでに

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage

These all generally mean whilst & during but I still (after ages of trying) make mistakes on where to use which one.

For anyone who knows the ins-and-outs of these grammar points, please explain them to me. 
‍♀️ I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: http://nifongo.style.coocan.jp/054.htm, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2620/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64786/7810...