# How to parse わかってるって 例のニセモノがやったに決まってんだ

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

Shoudn't there be a nominalizer after やった? I think it's just a casual contracion, but have not seen it before. Moreover, I have seen 決まっているだろう, or contracted to 決まってんだろう before, but in this particular example there's just だ, and that I do not understand.
At last, the って in わかってるって serves just to sort of emphasize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 決まってんだ is a contraction of 決まってるんだ (which in turn is a contraction of 決まっているのだ). See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010).

Next, you don't need a nominalizer (の) before に決まっている **even in formal writings**. It's not incorrect to put の, but it's much less common in reality. に can safely take the 終止形 (dictionary) form of a verb in several types of contexts:

- ～するに決まっている, ～するに違いない, ～するに相違ない
- ～するには (meaning "in order to")
- 言うに(は), 見るに, 思うに, etc. ([What does the に do in 表情から察するに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/5010))
- ～する[にしては](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-ni-shite-wa-meaning/) (meaning "for", "considering")
- ～する[にしろ](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9B%E3%82%88-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D-ni-seyo-ni-shiro-meaning/), ～するにせよ, ～するにしても, ～するにしたって (meaning "even if")
- ～する[につけ](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6-ni-tsuke-te-meaning/) (meaning "whenever")
- ～するに留まる

Basically you have to memorize these patterns as-is. I think the following questions are related to the reason why に can sometimes take a "bare" verb/adjective:

- [How can （の）目指すは be grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12538/5010)
- [Zero-nominalisation - Why and When?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4489/5010)

(By the way, this reminded me of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104546/80278) in English Language Stack Exchange.)