# What is the grammatical difference between べきは and べきことは

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I usually see べき nominalized as べきは. Is it grammatically correct or just a casual way of saying? How is it different form べきことは?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

べきは is a more pompous, not casual, way of saying べきことは.

- 今やるべきことは待つことだ。
  今やるべきは待つことだ。
  What we should now is wait.

べき is the attributive (連体) form of べし, and using it like a noun is basically an old way of speaking Japanese, although this is found in many patterns of modern Japanese:

- [Plain Verb followed by がよい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64661/5010)
- [How can （の）目指すは be grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12538/5010)

That said, べき is already a stilted word, so the difference between べきは and べきことは is not very large.

Comment: Just confirming: is べし the 終止形?

Comment: @Manab Yes. https://www.kotenbunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%97/